# PHP REST API обработка исключений

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Есть метод в API, который создает ордер. При удачном выполнении запроса ответ возвращает созданный orderID с остальной информацией. Может быть ситуация, когда система перегружена и вместо созданного ордера возвращается соответствующая ошибка (system overload). Суть вопроса состоит в том, чтобы выполнить данный ордер в любом случае, как только это станет возможно. Каким образом это было бы корректно реализовать в рамках laravel? Не могу воспроизвести алгоритм действий. В голову пока приходят очереди.

Comment: Очереди это верный подход. Но у вас проблема-то в другом. Так как у вас api, то api-клиент ожидает ответ типа "да, создано" или "нет, не создано". Как вы __потом__ сообщите api-клиенту что его заказ создан?

Answer (score 0):

1. Веб хуки, отправлять веб хук с информацией о завершении запроса.
2. Указать в ответе через какое время следует проверить статус запроса. Повторный запрос с идентификатором прошлого запроса